# Counter for a data from HTML file

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a task which we list 10 things from an HTML with using regex.

I managed to list 10 things from a website, but I need numbers next to them while displaying on tkinter.

For example 1 to 10 and/or 10 to 1 like this:
example:
[image: example]

I know I need to use a for loop but I don't know how, and have been researching for quite a while.

Here is my code for one of my windows:

```
def hidden_gems_on_disney_window():
    hidden_gems_on_disney = Tk()
    hidden_gems_on_disney['bg'] = 'pink'
    hidden_gems_on_disney.title('10 Hidden Gems On Disney+')
    hidden_gems_on_disney.geometry('500x500')
    Label(hidden_gems_on_disney, text = '10 Hidden Gems On Disney+ You Totally Missed', bg = 'SeaGreen2', font = ('Calibri', 15)).place(x=50, y=45)
    url = 'https://screenrant.com/disney-plus-hidden-gems/'
    web_page = urlopen(url)
    web_page_contents = web_page.read().decode('UTF-8')
#the pattern that I found to list my top 10.
    regex = r'(?<=</span>)(.*)(?=</h2>)'
#-------------------------------------------
    disney_plus = re.findall(regex, web_page_contents)
    x_coord = 40
    y_coord = 90
#This for loop shows top 10 contents on this website. There are already just 10 names, so in this case, it is not neccasery to use counter.
    for hidden_gems in disney_plus:
        Label(hidden_gems_on_disney, text = hidden_gems, bg ='pink', font = ('Malgun', 10)).place(x= x_coord, y= y_coord)
        y_coord = y_coord + 38
#Label for the hyperlink. Once clicked, it opens a browser and shows the webpage where data comes from.
    most_popular_songs_link = Label(hidden_gems_on_disney, text = 'https://screenrant.com/disney-plus-hidden-gems/', fg='dark green')
    most_popular_songs_link.place(x = 110, y = 475)
    most_popular_songs_link.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: callback(url))
    
    mainloop()
```

This is the output for this window.:
[image: This is the output for this window.]

Since this website ranks 10 to 1, I want to display numbers from 10 to 1 but would also like to see how to do for 1 to 10 if it's any different.

Comment: Please show what code you have so far for the tkinter GUI. What kind of widget do you use to display the list?

Comment: By the way, using `place()` is an unnecessary complication, `.pack()` or `.grid()` are easier to use (no need to compute offset so that widgets don't overlap).

Comment: why did you remove your posted code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate()` function in the `for` loop:

```
font = ('Malgun', 10)
for i, hidden_gems in enumerate(disney_plus[::-1], 1):  # in reverse order
    Label(hidden_gems_on_disney, text='{})'.format(i), bg='pink', font=font).place(x=x_coord, y=y_coord)
    Label(hidden_gems_on_disney, text=hidden_gems, bg='pink', font=font).place(x=x_coord+25, y=y_coord)
    y_coord += 38
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter in your loop.

```
#This for loop shows top 10 contents on this website. There are already just 10 names, so in this case, it is not neccasery to use counter.
    counter=10;
    for hidden_gems in disney_plus:
        Label(hidden_gems_on_disney, text = str(counter) + ". " + hidden_gems, bg ='pink', font = ('Malgun', 10)).place(x= x_coord, y= y_coord)
        y_coord = y_coord + 38
        counter = counter -1
```

In case you want increasing counter, initialize with `counter=1` and increment with `counter = counter +1`